# Excel VBA filldown to last row used in previous column

Tags: excel, vba

I've been looking all afternoon for the answer to this.

the code works as I want (after lots of time researching, I'm rather green to this) except I'd like to fill down to the last row used in previous column rather than the whole sheet.

I can't give exact referece to the previous column because it isn't always in the same place hence why I am looking it up and doing everything based on that look up result.

All answers I have found use the Range command but I can't find how to use my colNum variable for that.

```
Sub cndob()
'
' cndob change dob
'
' find column number and select
'
    Dim colNum As Integer
    colNum = WorksheetFunction.Match("BDate", Range("1:1"), 0)
    Columns(colNum + 1).Select

' insert column right

    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

' formula fill down
    Cells(2, colNum + 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RIGHT(RC[-1],2)&CHAR(47)&MID(RC[-1],5,2)&CHAR(47)&LEFT(RC[-1],4)"
    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).FillDown
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

The [`Range.Offset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx) property is the perfect solution for this. Change your last line of code to:

```
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).End(xlDown)).FillDown
```

The first argument to `.Offset` is the row offset. That we don't want to change. The column offset, though, is set to one to the left of the active column.

Comment: Thanks I was at work when I posted the question and will try tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly do you want to do, but from what I understood, something like this will do the job:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim colNum      As Long
    Dim sht         As Worksheet
    Dim rng         As Range

    Set sht = ActiveSheet

    colNum = WorksheetFunction.Match("BDate", Range("1:1"), 0)

    Set rng = sht.Cells(1, colNum)

    rng.Offset(0, 1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    rng.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=1+1"

    Range(rng, rng.End(xlDown)).Offset(0, 1).FillDown

End Sub
```

What it does? It looks for a cell "Bdate" on the first row and if it finds it, it inserts column to the right (if not, it gives an error :)). After this, it inserts a formula `1+1` for each cell, which is to the right. Anyhow, something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, setting range with a variable is a useful pointer too.  I'm a tax accountant by trade so tend to only look for code when I need it and have never learned this stuff in the right order.